# What happens if I populate both the text and html fields of a timeline item?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Both text and html fields of a timeline item render the content of a timeline card. What happens if I populate both `timelineItem.text` and `timelineItem.html` fields?

e.g.

```
POST /mirror/v1/timeline HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {auth token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{ "text": "Hello world",
"html": "I am a kitty" }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your value for `timelineItem.html` will trump the value supplied for `timelineItem.text`.

This is explained in more detail in the [`timelineItem` resource reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#html):

> If both `text` and `html` are provided for an item, the `html` will be
>   rendered in the timeline.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I created a timeline item with both fields populated and I noticed that when I shared this timeline item on Google+, Google+ took the text rather than the html.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand why you asked. That's a bit more complicated. When a timeline card is shared, the receiving Glassware has access to all fields on the item. It's up to that Glassware (in this case G+) to decide what fields it wants to use and how. In this case it sounds like the G+ Glassware is behaving unexpectedly, but it does illustrate why it is important for both values to have the same meaning (if you decide to supply both).